# Como renomear arquivos em uma lista .CSV na sua saida com PHP e CURL?

Tags: php, libcurl

como estão todos?
Este é meu primeiro post pois sou iniciante com PHP e CURL e necessitei criar um script que efetua-se o Download de varias imagens em repositórios através de um arquivo .csv.
Ele Lê a url onde esta o Arquivo, e salva em um diretório pre-estabelecido, eu uso a função "basename" para recuperar o nome da imagem que está na URL.
Até ai o script faz tudo sem problemas salva as imagens certinhas tudo de forma correta, mas não consigo mudar esta saída para renomear os arquivos conforme a necessidade que tenho.
Gostaria de saber se consigo usando o mesmo .csv acrescentar mais uma coluna, ou inserir no script os nomes específicos para cada imagem, ou seja, eu já sei qual seria este nome e a ordem de renomear seria a que estiver no .CSV, vejam o script:

```
<?php

$csvFile = file('imagensuno.csv'); // Aqui ele pega o arquivo .csv com as URL das imagens 

foreach ($csvFile as $line) {

  $url = str_getcsv($line);

  $ch = curl_init($url[0]);

  $name = basename($url[0]); //Aqui ele usa o nome da imagens na URL para salvar ela com o nome que ela tem na URL


if (!file_exists('G:\cca_imagens/' . $name)) {
    $fp = fopen('G:\cca_imagens/' . $name, 'wb');

  }

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  fclose($fp);

  //echo str_getcsv($line);

}
```

a função `str_getcsv`, eu vou percorrer linha a linha do arquivo csv “imagensuno.csv” que está localizado no mesmo diretório do script.

a `file_exists` que irá verificar se a imagem já foi salva antes, muito útil caso a execução do script seja interrompida.

Repare também na utilização da função `basename` para recuperar o nome da imagem que está na URL.

E é aqui que fica a minha dúvida, e não consigo lembrar se posso ou consigo fazer com que salve o nome que preciso que seria assim:

Ex de arquivo .csv

```
Coluna 1                                        Coluna 2
https://enderecodaimagens.com.br/img/foto.png,  foto.png => sku435.png, 
https://enderecodaimagens.com.br/img/foto2.png, foto2.png => sku444.png, 
https://enderecodaimagens.com.br/img/foto3.png  foto.png => sku865.png
```

Como estariam todos no mesmo .csv eu quero renomear estas não pelo nome da URL mas pela ação da Coluna 2, mas não sei se é possível, não consigo pensar em como fazer esta saída.

Gente preciso deste Help e se alguém quiser usar o script esta a disposição e logico quiser melhorar ele também acho muito bom ok?

abs

Comment: O arquivo 'imagensuno.csv' é o arquivo que possue as duas colunas, e você quer selecionar a imagem relacionada com a coluna 1 e renomear com o nome da coluna 2, é isso ?

Comment: Sim, ou caso possa fazer este procedimento de outra forma. Penso no .csv para que fique tudo em uma unica execução e arquivo, pois em media isso ira ocorrer com em média 25000 imagens

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você tenha um `.csv` com o seguinte formato:

```
http://127.0.0.1/stack/fopencsv/imagem1.jpg, novaimagem1.jpg
http://127.0.0.1/stack/fopencsv/imagem2.jpg, novaimagem2.jpg
http://127.0.0.1/stack/fopencsv/imagem3.jpg, novaimagem3.jpg
http://127.0.0.1/stack/fopencsv/imagem4.jpg, novaimagem4.jpg
http://127.0.0.1/stack/fopencsv/imagem5.jpg, novaimagem5.jpg
```

Você pode renomear usando a função [rename](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rename.php) do php, e [fgescsv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php) com o seguinte script:

```
<?php

//Abrindo o manipulador
$handle = fopen('csv.csv', 'r');

$count = 1;
$file = fgetcsv($handle);
//Abrindo o arquivo e lendo as linhas
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    //removendo a url (url não é aceita no 'rename')
    $name = str_replace('http://127.0.0.1/stack/fopencsv/img/','',$row[0]);
    $rename = $row[1];

    echo 'Arquivo original: ' . $name . '<br>Arquivo renomeado: ' . $rename . '<br>-<br>'.PHP_EOL;
    //Testa se o arquivo existe
    //use __dir__ , ou outra coisa, o importante é apontar o local correto do arquivo, dentro do mesmo servidor.
    if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '\\' . $name)) {
        //Teste para renomear o arquivo
        if (rename(__DIR__ . '\img\\' . $name, __DIR__ . '\img\\' . $rename)) {
            echo 'Arquivo original: ' . $name . '<br>Arquivo renomeado: ' . $rename . '<br>Status: Renomeado com sucesso, linha ' . $count . '<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'Arquivo original: ' . $name . '<br>Arquivo renomeado: ' . $rename . '<br>Status: Erro ao renomear, linha ' . $count . '<br>';
        }
    }
    $count += 1;
}
```

Regras:

1 - Os arquivos devem estar no mesmo servidor de onde o script é executado.

2 - Substitua a url de onde está o arquivo pelo caminho local.

3 - Meus arquivos estão na pasta:
Script:
c:\xampp\htdocs\stack\fgetscsv\
Imagens:
c:\xampp\htdocs\stack\fgetscsv\img

4 - Dê permissão ao arquivo (provavelmente já está ok)

Comment: O script vai renomear as "imagens" no próprio .CSV?

Comment: Não, esse script vai renomear as imagens mesmo, você quer renomear o csv ?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, o script deus vários Warnings:

Comment: Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in diretorio\muda.php on line 4

Comment: Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in diretorio\muda.php on line 8

Comment: Estou procurando ajustar!

Comment: A primeira mensagem do fopen é porque você precisa indicar como vai ser aberto o arquivo, informe 'r', e o segundo erro é porque seu fopen não abriu o arquivo, edita a pergunta com o código deste erro

Comment: Assim: $handle = fopen('imagensmudanome.csv','r');

Comment: Você está em linux ou windows ?

Comment: Agora erros somente nas 2 linhas: Warning: rename(C:\wamp\www\projetos\dw foto cca$name,C:\wamp\www\projetos\dw foto cca$rename): O sistema n�o pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. (code: 2) in C:\wamp\www\projetos\dw foto cca\muda.php on line 18   Notice: fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character in C:\wamp\www\projetos\dw foto cca\muda.php on line 8

Comment: Alias usando Windows!

Comment: @AndersonLeãoGimenes não testei esse script, vou testar aqui ja atualizo a resposta

Comment: Ok, eu aguardo!

Comment: @AndersonLeãoGimenes veja se agora você consegue aplicar, esse script funcionou, as imagens foram renomeadas, preste atenção na questão da url no nome, o rename não vai entender, então tem um str_replace para remover..

Comment: após uma batalha com a saúde, voltei peço desculpas por não retornar antes mas estava impossibilitado mesmo. Bem não avancei no código, os erros continuam no script que vc passou, o meu baixa as imagens das URL e nomeia com o nome que ela tem no link. Mas ainda não consigo renomeá-las como necessito. Como posso passar o código agora para alguém mais me ajudar, estou perdido.

Answer (score 0):

Arquivo renomeado: '.$rename.'
-
';
  //Testa se o arquivo existe
  if (!file_exists('C:\wamp\www\projetos\dw foto cca/' . $name)) {
    //Teste para renomear o arquivo
    if(rename("C:\wamp\www\projetos\dw foto cca\$name", "C:\wamp\www\projetos\dw foto cca\$rename")){
       echo 'Arquivo original: '.$name. '
Arquivo renomeado: '.$rename.'
Status: Renomeado com sucesso, linha '.$count.'
';
    }else{
       echo 'Arquivo original: '.$name. '
Arquivo renomeado: '.$rename.'
Status: Erro ao renomear, linha '.$count.'
';
    }
  }
  $count +=1;
}

?>

Este acima o código editado!

Comment: Quando precisar acrescentar alguma informação a pergunta, clique em editar e coloque junto na pergunta anterior, o lugar de respostas é apenas para resposta, faça um tour pra entender melhor como o site funciona: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour